# Remote debug web service in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

I've followed all the steps shown in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019) but couldn't get VS 2019 to stop the execution in the breakpoint that I've set.
After attaching VS 2019 to the correct w3wp.exe process, I've used WCF Test Client to call the .asmx service on the remote server but the execution goes just like before, when there was nothing attached to it.

Comment: Is the assembly of w2wp.exe the same version as your code, or did the code change ?

Comment: @andymeissner it is the same and VS is set to Debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way I've deployed the binaries was wrong. Instead of building the project and copying the files from the bin folder to the server, now I've used the Publish option and it worked.